# Make a tkinter grid staggered

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, tkinter-canvas

I am using this grid.py coloring program here https://scipython.com/blog/a-simple-colouring-grid/
The relevant code that makes the grid is

```
self.cells = []
    for iy in range(n):
        for ix in range(n):
            xpad, ypad = pad * (ix+1), pad * (iy+1)
            x, y = xpad + ix*xsize, ypad + iy*ysize
            rect = self.w.create_rectangle(x, y, x+xsize,
                                       y+ysize, fill=UNFILLED)
            self.cells.append(rect)
```

I was wondering if I could get it so the squares stagger as shown below:

[image: staggered grid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add/subtract a "stagger offset" for each x coordinates of the cells on a given row. The sign of the value determined by the rank of the 'row' by multiplying the offset by `(-1)**row`.

Maybe like this?:

```
    self.cells = []
    for row in range(n):
        stagger_offset = (xsize // 4) * (-1)**row   # will be positive for even rows, negative otherwise
        y0 = pad * (row + 1) + row * ysize
        y1 = y0 + ysize
        for col in range(n):
            x0 = pad * (col + 1) + col * xsize + stagger_offset
            x1 = x0 + xsize
            self.cells.append(self.w.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=UNFILLED))
```

You may have to insert half cells at the beginning/end of even/odd rows, depending on what visual aspect you prefer.